# files in ipad device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunesconnect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use iTunes USB File Transfer to copy files from PC to Apple iPad, e.g. PDF files for viewer app?](https://superuser.com/questions/132293/how-to-use-itunes-usb-file-transfer-to-copy-files-from-pc-to-apple-ipad-e-g-pd)

is it possible to load other file like video,music  into device directly through itune?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/132293/how-to-use-itunes-usb-file-transfer-to-copy-files-from-pc-to-apple-ipad-e-g-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not without a specific app that you can load those files into.  In other words, the iOS devices do not have a built-in handler for HTML files loaded through the iTunes interface, however there may be an app that will handle these files which will accept them through iTunes.

Comment: do u know any app like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UIWebView class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can use the methods:

```
– loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:
– loadHTMLString:baseURL:
```

to load HTML or other media in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a file synch app called dropbox http://www.dropbox.com/ which is free for up to 2GB. You can get clients for iPad, iPhone/iPod touch, blackberry, android, yadda yadda..., and most major desktop OSes.